# Как отправить данные по открытому ssh каналу с сервера на клиент?

Tags: linux, c, ssh

Предположим у меня есть удаленный рабочий хост к которому я конекчусь через ssh. Могу ли я через уже открытые ssh канал посылать данные с сервера на клиент. Тоесть как пример, я работаю в удаленном терминале, тем временем утилита в фоновом режиме посылает данные по тому же каналу. Нужно понять возможно ли это сделать вообще, на каком языке не важно

Comment: Можете: tcp-туннель, sftp - выбирайте на свой вкус

Comment: @andreymal, можно более подробно?

Comment: @andreymal, хотелось бы не открывать новое соединение, а использовать текущий ssh тунель

Comment: если будете писать на paramiko или c, то можно добавлять tcp каналы, sftp и простые пайпы не отключаясь. если просто ssh, то через параметры коммандной строки сразу открывай шел и тунель

Comment: Подробности в `man ssh`. Вы его читали?